# How do I set value of nested object to key of current object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

This array has the key to substitute with nested key of 'name'

```js
const arr = ['status', 'user', ...]  <-- This array contains key to be replaced with name
```

This is what my current response object is

```js
[
  {
    "id": 11,
    "location": "Mumbai",
    "status": {
      "name": "NEW"
    },
    "user": {
      "name": "Rakesh"
     }
  }
]
```

How do I modify the above array of objects to this below

```js
[
  {
    "id": 11,
    "location": "Mumbai",
    "status": "NEW",
    "user": "Rakesh"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can try below code

```js
const keys = ['status', 'user']
let arr = [
  {
    "id": 11,
    "location": "Mumbai",
    "status": {
      "name": "NEW"
    },
    "user": {
      "name": "Rakesh"
     }
  }
]

arr.map(a => keys.forEach(k => {
   if(a[k] && a[k].name) a[k] = a[k].name
}));

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This solution solved my problem. Thank you @MORE

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this one:

```js
const results = [
  {
    "id": 11,
    "location": "Mumbai",
    "status": {
      "name": "NEW"
    },
    "user": {
      "name": "Rakesh"
    }
  }, {
    "id": 12,
    "location": "Helsinki",
    "status": {
      "name": "NEW"
    },
    "user": {
      "name": "Samuli"
    }
  }
];

const flattenObject = ([key, value]) => ((typeof value === 'object') ? {[key] : value[Object.keys(value)[0]]} : {[key]: value});

const reduceToSingleObject = (acc, b) => ({...acc, ...b});

const actualResults = results.map((result) => Object.entries(result).map(flattenObject).reduce(reduceToSingleObject));


console.log(actualResults);
```

**Explanation:**

1. `flattenObject` is a function to flatten structure of object inside object. This only takes the first prop (without knowing the name of the key). If you, for some reason, would need to flatten several key-values, then it'd need whole different kind of helper function to sort that out.
2. `reduceToSingleObject` is a function to put all the key-value pairs into a single object. This could have been done already in flattenObject function, but for the clarity, I separated it to a normal **map - reduce** pattern.
3. `actualResults` is the outcome where we go through all the entries of your original results.

Comment: This also worked! Thank you @Samuli Hakoniemi